# Como executar scripts em Lua com programa java?

Tags: java, lua

Quero aprender a desenvolver, aliando mais de uma linguagem de programação, usando java com scripts em lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [LuaJ](http://www.luaj.org/luaj/3.0/README.html) oferece uma interface de integração bem simples entre o Java e o Lua.

```
import org.luaj.vm2.*;
import org.luaj.vm2.lib.jse.*;

Globals globals = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
LuaValue chunk = globals.loadfile("examples/lua/hello.lua"); // seu script lua
chunk.call();
```

Pode salvar o valor retornado de `chunk.call()` em uma variável. Esse é o resultado do script executado. [Fonte](https://github.com/luaj/luaj/blob/master/README.html)

- [Documentação de `LuaValue`](http://luaj.org/luaj/3.0/api/org/luaj/vm2/LuaValue.html)

O LuaJ é [totalmente código aberto e está no GitHub](https://github.com/luaj/luaj).